# Converting between struct cpu_set_t and struct bitmask

Tags: c, linux

Are there any routines to convert between struct cpu_set_t used by the cpu set API (i.e. CPU_ZERO, CPU_SET, etc.) and struct bitmask used by the numa functions that solve similar problems (i.e. numa_sched_setaffinity)?

I've found hwloc as a possible solution, I'm looking for a simpler solution.